# Spring upgradation for grails application

Tags: spring, grails

I have a grails web app. This uses grails-1.0.1 version. For some reason, I need to upgrade to higher version of Spring (4.2.3). Is it possible to upgrade to higher version of spring without upgrading to higher version of grails ?

Thanks,
Varun

Comment: Yes it's possible, but not in your case.

Comment: If I plan to upgrade to higher version of grails, which grails version should I upgrade to for compatibility with Spring-4.2.3 ?

Comment: By default grails 2.5 and 3, both support spring 4.1.x. You can first upgrade to grails 2.5 and then try to upgrade spring version to 4.2.3 by adding it to dependency list

Comment: Grails 2.5 is supported in most plugins,while grails 3 is a big step forward,and has the amazing gradle as the primary build automation, and alot more features. if you need alot of plugins, you might need to consider 2.5 first.